# React-select save props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

I am using the react-select to enable multiple selection on my UI. However, I need to get the props from this react-select as I would be sending the select values to the backend. I am wondering. How can I save the state values in the array. I did a console.log and I got the values as

```
0: {value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla"}
1: {value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry"}
2: {value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate"}.
```

However I would just like the value label as I would be sending this exact values for example vanilla to the backend. Any suggestions. Thanks a lot. The [github link](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select) for react-select is :

```
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { connect } from "react-redux";
    import PropTypes from "prop-types";
    import checkboxes from "./checkboxes";
    import Checkbox from "./Checkbox";
    import Select from "react-select";
    const options = [
      { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
      { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
      { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
    ];

    class CreatePreferences extends Component {
    state = {
    selectedOption: null
  };
  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    this.setState({ selectedOption });
    console.log(`Option selected:`, selectedOption);
  };
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;

    return (
      <Select
        value={selectedOption}
        isMulti
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        options={options}
      />
    );
  }
}
CreatePreferences.propTypes = {
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  profile: state.profile
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CreatePreferences);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things to do: you need a constructor to define a state and you need to update this state with the selected values.

[Online Sandbox Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/0mqmxl4lrp)

Define your state with a constructor, as...

```
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selectedOptions: [],
    };
  }
```

And define your event handler like so.  (You asked for "label" to be saved, normally it is "label" that is displayed and "value" that is saved, but, anyway, as requested...)...

```
  handleChange = selectedOption => {
    const state = this.state;
    state.selectedOptions = [];
    selectedOption.forEach((option) => {
      state.selectedOptions.push(option.label);
    });
    this.setState(state);
    console.log(`Options selected:`, JSON.stringify(state.selectedOptions, null, 4));
  };
```

Here, you will see the output like this...

```
Options selected: [
    "Chocolate"
]
Options selected: [
    "Chocolate",
    "Strawberry"
]
```

Normally, there is much to do in regards to have the `render()` function and the state work together, and that is always true in ReactJS.

But you seem to be using `React-Select`, which seems to handle some of this automatically: [React-Select Github Page](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select)